# Working of methods set_seq1 and set_seq2 , difflib python

Tags: python, python-2.7, difflib, sequencematcher

I have checked the docs of difflib and i'm confused on how [`difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio) actually works. Consider this :

```
s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "hey here" , "hey there").ratio()
print s
```

gives `s = 0.9411764705882353`
I wanted to know how exactly it is computed . The 2 strings are compared by actually looking at the deviation of one string w.r.t other.for 2 strings **a** and **b** The docs say :

**differences are computed as "what do we need to do to 'a' to change it into 'b'?"**

And there is something like :

**for x in b, b2j[x] is a list of the indices (into b) at which x appears; junk elements do not appear**

Please explain w.r.t the above example of **s** .

Comment: Seems like you should use `'` instead of `"`. Look:

`difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'hey there', 'hey there').ratio()`
is exacly 1.0

Comment: its "hey here" and "hey there" , the quotes don't make a difference. you have typed the wrong words..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Where T is the total number of elements in both sequences, and M is the number of matches, this is 2.0*M / T.

In this case, T is 17 because the first string has 8 characters and the second string has 9. M is 8 because eight characters from the first string match with characters from the second. 2 * 8 / 17 equals 0.9411764705882353.